# ffmpeg filter-complex concat without loss of quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

I am currently successfully concatenating two video files using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i './clip1.mov' -i './clip2.mp4' -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" merged.mp4
```

`Clip1.mov` and `Clip2.mp4` contain different video bitrates. After the merge the outputted `merged.mp4` birate is reduced significantly(compared to both input Clips). Is it possible to output the merged video to have approximately the same bitrate and audio bit rate as `Clip1`. IF so, a code snippet similar to the above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the quality, not the bitrate. But you can add `-crf 18` to increase bitrate.

Comment: @Mulvya how do i measure quality? also can you aloborate on what -crf does with the value 18 and where do i add it in the code above?

Comment: Add it after the maps. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264